# Function ignoring its argument(s)

Tags: c++, functional-programming, boost-hana, function-object

This is mostly a curiosity question.

I saw code like this (I'm not interested in what it does)

```cpp
constexpr auto xxx = boost::hana::overload(
    [](SomeType& x){ /* x is used and something is returned */ },
    [](SomeOtherType1&){ /* no-op in this case */ },
    [](SomeOtherType2&){ /* no-op in this case */ }
);
```

where the latter two lambdas just ignore their argument.

Since I know that `boost::hana::always` is to create a function which ignores its arguments and always returns the argument passed to `always`, I was wandering if Hana (or another library) offers a similar function to ignore one argument (or also all arguments), such that the two lambdas can be both replaced by, say, `blackHole`, which I know wouldn't really be a mathematical function.

When I saw a result on cppreference for [`std::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore) I was hurray-ing, but no... it's a totally different thing.

Answer (score 2):

So you basically are asking if there is a global function object or some class in a library that works like `[](auto &&) {}` when called? I do not know about such a function in the STL. C++20 adds [`std::identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/identity) that works like `[](auto &&in){return in;}` so not exactly what you want, but pretty near. Before `C++20` you could abuse other functions like [`std::as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) or `std::ignore::operator=` for this, though I do not know of a function that returns `void`.

EDIT: Regarding `std::ignore::operator=`: `std::ignore` is defined as an object such that `std::ignore = blub;` has no effect for any `blub`. This can also be written as `std::ignore.operator=(blub);`. But now that I think about it, that is not that helpful, since you cannot pass that function directly to e.g. an stl-algorithm, you would have to wrap it somehow.

Btw, my advise is that you define somewhere

```
const static auto do_nothing = [](auto &&){};
// Requires C++14, if you have C++17 available, use
constexpr auto do_nothing = [](auto &&){};
```

and be done with it. Abusing some STL functions can be confusing for people reading your code while an aptly named lambda has no problem at all.

Comment: What's the latter (`std::ignore::operator=`)? Can you give a link for it?